# problem converting pkcs12 file into a pem

Tags: x509certificate

I am trying to convert a client certificate from a pkcs12 type to a pem file using openssl, but this error is showed on my terminal. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? I haven't edited or manually changed the p12 file. Even when I try to get some info from the .p12 file it shows error.

```
# openssl pkcs12 -in Desktop/cert.p12 -nokeys -out Desktop/cert-file.pem
139728018543680:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1130:
139728018543680:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:290:Type=PKCS12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cert looks like a PEM certificate which you are converting to PEM again.

Just edit the certificate by keeping only the contents between `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` and then try. It should work.

**Example:**

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```